# Input field auto-populating with spaces and highlighting issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Really strange issue with an input field on my login form. It appears it is being populated with a whole bunch of "spaces" and then these spaces are highlighted immediately upon page load. As a result the placeholder text does not show.

Here's what it looks like upon screen load:

[image]

And the direct link for you to have a look at as well: https://www.uncvrd.co/wp-login.php

*EDIT* relavant `wp-login.php`

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login">
            <?php _e( 'Username or Email Address' ); ?>
                <br />
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" <?php echo $aria_describedby_error; ?> class="input" value="
                <?php echo esc_attr( $user_login ); ?>" size="20" />
        </label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass">
            <?php _e( 'Password' ); ?>
                <br />
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" <?php echo $aria_describedby_error; ?> class="input" value="" size="20" /></label>
    </p>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: show us the php code of your login form

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan Hi! Sure, it's rather long, give me one second to post it

Comment: @Md.KhairulHasan added relevant section. looks like it is trying to pull php in `value` field but just gettin blank spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its problem with your input element. It is observed that you have predefined spaces in to the user input

```
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login"  class="input" value="
                                                            " size="20" />
```

You need to edit this and make it:

```
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login"  class="input" value="" size="20" />
```

It will work

For your php code: you want to do it as:

```
<input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" <?php echo $aria_describedby_error; ?> class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user_login ); ?>" size="20" />
```

Basically it is sending empty value, but there is already predefined space which is caused due to your html tags

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. There is some included php in that `value` element. I'm not quite sure if it is ok to delete that element?

Comment: ah ok figured out the issue, but will give you the credit since it got me on the right trail. My code editor was "beautifying" the code upon saving and moved the php ` <?php echo esc_attr( $user_login ); ?>` to a new line...therefore adding spaces. By turning off beautify text and moving the text back into proper location, this fixed the issue. Thanks!